# Scrape MTA Subway data?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have an interesting problem on my hands, and I was wondering if someone here who is much smarter and much more experienced with this kind of thing can give some insight.

Basically, I need the full list of train stops for a couple MTA Subway line trains. Here's how the data is displayed on the mta.info website, for the #3 line, as an example

http://web.mta.info/nyct/service/threelin.htm

Is there anyway I can scrape this data, and maybe write it to a text or csv file? If so, how would I go about something like that? I feel like this could possibly be done in Python, but I'm not sure as I've just started creating things with Python only 2 days ago(I'm a Java guy).

I'm trying to avoid actually writing each of these out to a document manually, but if there's no other choice, I guess I will have to do it. I just need the data

If there's any scripting pros out there than could possibly point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [free API](http://web.mta.info/developers/) available as @rjbman pointed out. Also see:

- [is there an api for the new york mta subway/bus/train etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809375/is-there-an-api-for-the-new-york-mta-subway-bus-train-etc)
- [MTA-API python wrapper](https://github.com/mimouncadosch/MTA-API)

But, here's an alternative solution involving HTML parsing using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://web.mta.info/nyct/service/threelin.htm"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
table = soup.find('table', summary='Table of 3 Subway Line Stops')
stops = [tr('td')[2].text.strip().replace('\n', '').split(' /') 
         for tr in table('tr', height=25)]
print stops
```

Prints all of the stops as a list of lists:

```
[
    [u'Harlem-148 Street', u'7 Avenue'], 
    [u'145 Street', u'Lenox Avenue'], 
    ...
    [u'Van Siclen Avenue', u'Livonia Avenue'], 
    [u'New Lots Avenue', u'Livonia Avenue']
]
```

For getting the page content I've used [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module.

Comment: Dude, you are a lifesaver! Thank you. It's amazing just how powerful of a language Python is, can't believe I'm just getting into it! Way less verbose than Java as well. I can leverage your code, passing in a list of urls and writing the output of the lists to a CSV or text file. Cheers man!

Comment: @JadeByfield I would still try with an API first - try that `MTA-API` python wrapper that I've linked. Leave html-parsing approach as the last resort here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they have a developer API available at http://web.mta.info/developers/ .

Barring that, there's a couple different Python libraries that will allow you to parse HTML code; I'm preferential to [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#) myself. You can pull the information you need off the webpage then output it using [file out](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Answer (score 1):

**Short version**:

Here's a list of all of the lines and all of the stops belonging to each line:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/loisaidasam/sub/5369ebc22ef57b932d57066a357fd4cd5a41a402/stops_per_subway_line.txt

**Long version**:

I wrote a little Python helper library for parsing data from MTA's Developer Resources:

https://github.com/loisaidasam/sub

The MTA has made available some Developer Resources:

http://web.mta.info/developers/

And specifically some static content about the MTA subway system, provided you read and abide by these developer data terms:

http://web.mta.info/developers/developer-data-terms.html

Direct link to download static subway data:

http://web.mta.info/developers/data/nyct/subway/google_transit.zip

Enjoy!